# Use ng-repeat for a json array selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I did this page:

[CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/hISwTllbaa60Vlpld7Nk?p=preview) (watch the second Fork, in the middle, not the last one)

that there are two selection: the second one is empty and auto complete with a subarray of the option chosen in the first select. This works.

Now, this is for a table that I'm doing. In fact the rows contain the two selection above. I will add also a button for ADD new line, so with new selection. I've tried to iterate, but of course it doesn't work.... In this update [THIS](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bOxIW2JJIhRUGCuVMzx?p=preview) you can see that in the script.js i've added new code (i made comments). I've created one array to include all the info, one function to add new line and one function to delete line. But of course it doesn't work....... what I am doing wrong?

In particular this is the new lines of js' code:

```
 $scope.allInfo = [
  {
     "Product ID" : $scope.selectedProduct.id,
     "Product Nome" : $scope.selectedProduct.nome,
     "Product Codice": $scope.selectedProduct.codice,
     "Lot ID" : $scope.selectedLot.id,
     "Lot Value" : $scope.selectedLot.value
  }   
 ];

$scope.foods = [
 {
  "select1": "",
  "select2": ""
 }
]


$scope.newLine = function () {
  var itemToAdd = { "select1": "", "select2": ""};
 $scope.allInfo.push(itemToAdd);
}

$scope.removeLine = function (itemIndex) {
  $scope.foods.splice(itemIndex, 1);
 }
```

I mean to repeat the whole line, repeat the select. At the beginning i have: `<select></select> <select></select> <button></button> <button></button>`. When i press add line, i would to duplicate`<select></select> <select></select> <button></button> <button></button>`. Make completely a new line, with new field! So iterate the function.

Thank you very much in advice!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

mate, watch this :

```
 $scope.newLine = function () {
var itemToAdd = { "select1":   $scope.selectedProduct, "select2": $scope.selectedLot};
    $scope.allInfo.push(itemToAdd);
}
```

your code was :

```
$scope.newLine = function () {
var itemToAdd = { "select1": , "select2": ""};
$scope.allInfo.push(itemToAdd);
}
```

which I did not understand, the code now seems working for me...
updated code plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/A0Uh7jJUuJgWBBVKKjiU?p=preview

Comment: No, it adds the line in the {{allInfo}} , i want to duplicate the <select> button!! Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/3DrWMSssx5UaQfHADoEr?p=preview

Comment: @panagulis72, give me a sec, i am updating

Comment: It doesnt work, because when I add a new line, and I select a product, it changes also the previous selected item!

Comment: @panagulis72, Im on it now, wait